# What is the logical difference between these two classes?

Tags: java, object, logic

I have written a Java class to solve a problem in the textbook, Javanotes 7, which asks for a program that displays statistics related to the number of rolls it takes to get a given value on a pair of dice. My class does not give me the correct statistics, yet—as far as I can tell—it is logically identical to the solution given in the textbook. Obviously it is not.
Here is my code:

```
/**
    This program rolls a pair of dice until they come up a certain value. It repeats this for a certain number of trials and then gives the user the average number of
    rolls required to achieve the target value. It does this for each possible value of two six-sided dice. It also gives the standard deviation and the maximum
    number of rolls.
*/

public class DiceAverage{

    static final int SAMPLE_SIZE = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Total on Dice    Average Number of Rolls    Standard Deviation    Maximum Number of Rolls");
        System.out.println("-------------    -----------------------    ------------------    -----------------------");

        //each dice value iterator
        for(int i = 2; i < 13; i ++){

            //for each value, create a Statcalc, and PairOfDice object
            StatCalc dataset = new StatCalc();
            PairOfDice dice = new PairOfDice();

            //each trial iterator
            for(int j = 0; j < SAMPLE_SIZE; j ++){

                int counter = 1;//counter for number of rolls. Initialized at 1 because dice object is rolled upon construction.

                //get die1 and die2
                while(dice.getDie1() + dice.getDie2() != i){

                    dice.roll();
                    counter ++;

                }

                dataset.enter(counter);

            }

            System.out.printf("      %-19d%-25.3f%-25.3f%1.3f%n", i, dataset.getMean(), dataset.getStandardDeviation(), dataset.getMax());

        }

    }

}
```

And here is the actual solution:

```
/**This program performs the following type of experiment:
 * Given a desired total roll, such as 7, roll a pair of
 * dice until the given total comes up, and count how many
 * rolls are necessary.  Now do the experiment over and over,
 * and find the average number of rolls.  The number of times
 * the experiment is repeated is given by the constant,
 * NUMBER_OF_EXPERIMENTS.  Several statistics are computed and
 * printed out for each possible roll = 2, 3, ..., 12:
 * the average number of rolls, the standard deviation,
 * and the maximum number of rolls.
 */

public class DiceRollStats2 {

   static final int NUMBER_OF_EXPERIMENTS = 10000;

   private static PairOfDice dice = new PairOfDice();
            // A single pair of dice, which will be used for all
            // the experiments.


   public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.out.println("Dice Total   Avg # of Rolls   Stand. Deviation   Max # of Rolls");
       System.out.println("----------   --------------   ----------------   --------------");

       for ( int total = 2;  total <= 12;  total++ ) {
          StatCalc stats;  // An object that will compute the statistics.
          stats = new StatCalc();
          for ( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_EXPERIMENTS; i++ ) {
                // Do the experiment of counting the number of rolls
                // required to roll the desired total, and enter the
                // number of rolls into stats' dataset.
             stats.enter( rollFor(total) );
          }
          System.out.printf("%6d", total);
          System.out.printf("%18.3f", stats.getMean());
          System.out.printf("%19.3f", stats.getStandardDeviation());
          System.out.printf("%14.3f", stats.getMax());
          System.out.println();
       }

   } // end main

   /**
    * Roll the dice repeatedly until the total on the
    * two dice comes up to be N.  N MUST be one of the numbers
    * 2, 3, ..., 12.  (If not, this routine will go into an
    * infinite loop!).  The number of rolls is returned.
    */
   static int rollFor( int N ) {
       int rollCt = 0;  // Number of rolls made.
       do {
          dice.roll();
          rollCt++;
       } while ( dice.getDie1() + dice.getDie2() != N );
       return rollCt;
   }


}  // end class DiceRollStats2
```

I cannot see the logical difference between these. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int rollCt = 0;  // Number of rolls made.
   do {
      dice.roll();
      rollCt++;
   } while ( dice.getDie1() + dice.getDie2() != N );
   return rollCt;
```

Here the dice are rolled before the boolean test in the do...while loop.

```
int counter = 1;//counter for number of rolls. Initialized at 1 because dice object is rolled upon construction.

            //get die1 and die2
            while(dice.getDie1() + dice.getDie2() != i){

                dice.roll();
                counter ++;

            }
```

Whereas here the dice are rolled after the boolean test. So if the dice become equal to i, the dice values are never changed by roll()—as the while loop is skipped—and you get a bunch of iterations through the for loop with count == 1. Basically, the dice roll is not simulated properly this way.

Answer (score 0):

You are counting 1 extra roll by initializing `int counter = 1;`

Try initializing it with 0.

Comment: PairOfDice objects are automatically rolled when constructed. This is why I initialize counter as 1.